# RGB Color Transparency

Tags: colors, bitmap, transparency, rgb

Does a color transparency give us a new color? for example - If a color is made to be 50% opaque, would that make a new color or would it be just 50% transparent of original color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the RGB values are the same. The transparency and the opacity don't change them.